# Check if model instance falls within named_scope in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, named-scope

Assume I have a named scope:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    named_scope :bar, :conditions => 'some_field = 1'
end
```

This works great for queries and I have a bunch of useful named_scopes defined. What I would like is to be able to do this:

```
f = Foo.find(:first)
f.some_field = 1
f.is_bar? #=> true
```

The '.bar?' method will simply return true or false if the model instance falls within the named scope. Is there anyway to do this without writing an 'is_bar?' method even though I've already written a good way to check if something 'is_bar?' If I remember correctly, DRY is good so any help would be greatly appreciated/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can call the `exists?` method on a named scope which will query the database to see if the given record exists with those conditions.

```
Foo.bar.exists?(f)
```

However this will not work if you have changed the attributes on `f` and not saved it to the database. This is because the named scope conditions are SQL so the check must happen there. Attempting to convert to Ruby `if` conditions is messy, especially in more complex scenarios.

Comment: thanks. Ok so pretend I called .save after changing the value. 
Foo.bar.exists?(Foo.find(:first)) will return true or false depending if it falls within the bar scope? Awesome.

Comment: Correct. You shouldn't have to call Find again either. "f.save; Foo.bar.exists?(f)" should work.

Comment: Has this gotten any easier since 2009?

Comment: It might have gotten harder. There is now a deprecation warning: "DEPRECATION WARNING: You are passing an instance of ActiveRecord::Base to `exists?`. Please pass the id of the object by calling `.id`." So now it should be `Foo.bar.exists?(f.id)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your scopes are simple, you probably want to avoid code duplication. My solution allows you to call `model.active?` to know if an instance belongs to the scope, and `Model.active` to find all records matching the scope. `model.active?` doesn't involve any database queries.

consider adding this to `config/initializers/scope_and_method.rb`:

```
require 'active_record/named_scope'

module ActiveRecord::NamedScope::ClassMethods
  def scope_and_method field, *values
    field = field.to_sym
    values.each do |value|
      named_scope value.to_sym, :conditions => {field => value}
      define_method "#{value}?" do
        send(field.to_sym) == value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
scope_and_method :state, 'active', 'inactive'
```

Works as if it was:

```
named_scope :active, :conditions => {:state => 'active'}
named_scope :inactive, :conditions => {:state => 'inactive'}

def active?
  state == 'active'
end

def inactive?
  state == 'inactive'
end
```

This is a solution for Rails 2.3. This needs a very small tuning for Rails 3 and 4. (`named_scope` -> `scope`) I will check it soon.