# Check to See if A Particular Active Record Object Is In A Particular 'Scope'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Currently on save I am trying to check to see if a recorded falls into a particular 'scope'. This 'scope' really is just some saved arguments for a .where call. Also with this 'scope' I am only ever checking values of the object, not ever how it relates to other objects in the database, so querying the database will always be over kill if that makes sense.

I have only been able to come up with the below solution

```
begin
   result = self.class.where(scope).find(self.id)
rescue
  result = false
end
```

The issue with this is that I have to query the database even though I already have the record, and I have to run this not only before save but after save to check the values it was and the values it will be after save, because there is no way to query the database for the updated version if it hasn't been saved.

There can be a number of these checks so I would like to avoid having to do it twice, and also having to query the database that many times, even if ultimately I am just looking something up by id.

The only other solution I have been able to think of would be to have a method that some how translates the where call into a proc that return a boolean when passed an object. The only issue with that is translating it would some how have to work with the active record adapter being used, which seems like a whole project to its own. So does anyone know of some way to do this, or of a gem that would help?

PS I getting the 'scope' from cache so I can't save it as a proc because you can't put procs into the cache with Rails.

Comment: It may be helpful to provide a concrete example of the record you're saving, what the scope's conditions look like, and why you're trying to do this. There may be a better way to go about whatever it is exactly that you're trying to do.

Comment: The record could be anything and so could the scope as long as it doesn't require comparison to anything else in the database, its supposed to be reusable no matter the set up. It is though for a caching system. So basically if the record before or after save falls into a cache's 'scope' that cache gets deleted. Its for really complicated pages that you want to cache, but don't want to expire unless the updated record could possible be part of the cache.

Comment: same question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255815/check-if-model-instance-falls-within-named-scope-in-rails

Answer (score 6):

first you can improve your first solution a bit

```
result = self.class.where(scope).exists?(self.id)
```

if you don't want to check the database, why don't you just check if your object's attributes has the values of the scope? if your scope is

```
class.where(:attr1 => value1, :attr2 => value2, :attr3 => value3)
```

then you can do

```
result = self.attr1 == value1 and self.attr2 == value2 and self.attr3 == value3
```

Comment: The first part helps a lot, I don't know why I didn't think of that, got my head to far in it! 

The second part the issue is that I don't want to restrict the where statements to just the hash rocket set up. For instance on one project I am doing the scope is if the entry was published between two dates, and with that I would end up having to parse out what was given. Though that really does help me to start thinking in the right direction! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If your scopes are simple, you probably want to avoid code duplication. My solution allows you to call `model.active?` to know if an instance belongs to the scope, and `Model.active` to find all records matching the scope. `model.active?` doesn't involve any database queries.

consider adding this to `config/initializers/scope_and_method.rb`:

```
require 'active_record/named_scope'

module ActiveRecord::NamedScope::ClassMethods
  def scope_and_method field, *values
    field = field.to_sym
    values.each do |value|
      named_scope value.to_sym, :conditions => {field => value}
      define_method "#{value}?" do
        send(field.to_sym) == value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
scope_and_method :state, 'active', 'inactive'
```

Works as if it was:

```
named_scope :active, :conditions => {:state => 'active'}
named_scope :inactive, :conditions => {:state => 'inactive'}

def active?
  state == 'active'
end

def inactive?
  state == 'inactive'
end
```

This is a solution for Rails 2.3. This needs a very small tuning for Rails 3 and 4. (`named_scope` -> `scope`) I will check it soon.